# Attributes IF function - Displays custom product availability status

Tags: magento-1.8, php, product-attribute

I'm trying to have custom product availability messages displayed instead of the standard "In/Out of Stock" messages by using product attributes.

e.g "1-2 Weeks", "In Workshop" etc.

I've been editing these messages in template/catalog/product/view/type but I'm having a bit of trouble with the syntax and calling attributes correctly.

```
<?php
<?php if ($this->displayProductAttribute()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAttributeText('weeks')): ?>
 <p class="availability custom"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" /><?php echo $this->__('2-3 Weeks') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" /><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/OutOfStock" /><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
?>
```

Learning PHP as I go and I'm not 100% sure of Magento's native attribute call.
If somebody could have a quick scan and give me their thoughts I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong method `isAttributeText`

If you want to access the value of Product Attribute then

```
 $_product->getData('attribute_code');
```

End If you want tot Display Label Of that Attribute then

```
 $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code')
```

OR

```
 $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

And then you can check using `isset()` of PHP.

Hope you got Proper Answer.